# Product gallery not working properly in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mozilla, concrete5

I have a concret5 template in which there is a product gallery(slideshow). where in clients are given option to select different `color` for the cycle parts displayed in the gallery. Everything works fine, but in **mozilla**, before image appends to the gallery, it is displayed below the gallery as well.

Comment: Is it a custom template? Can you give a sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that giving the gallery container height and overflow hidden and giving the images margin bottom worked for me. This problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

This would most likely work with some javascript and custom css. It's impossible to address your issue without something to look at. The live site would be perfect.